# Async Function in AWS Lambda Alexa Intent with Yummly API

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await

I'm trying to retrieve data from the Yummly API through Amazon Alexa using ws-yummly in Node.js deployed on AWS Lambda. I'm fairly new to all aspects of this, but new to javascript in particular (Python is my 'native' language).

Here is what I have for my recommendation intent:

```
"RecommendationIntent": function () {
        // delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slots

        let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);

        if (!filledSlots) {
            return;
        }

        console.log("filled slots: " + JSON.stringify(filledSlots));
        // at this point, we know that all required slots are filled.
        let slotValues = getSlotValues(filledSlots);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(slotValues));

        const mainIngredientQuery = slotValues.mainIngredient.resolved;

                async function main (queryWord) {
                    const resp = await Yummly.query(queryWord)
                        .maxTotalTimeInSeconds(1400)
                        .maxResults(20)
                        .minRating(3)
                        .get();
                    const names = resp.matches.map(recipe => recipe.recipeName);
                    const speechOutput = String(names[0]);
                        this.response.speak(speechOutput);
                        this.emit(":responseReady");
                }
                main(mainIngredientQuery).catch(error => console.error(error))
    },
```

This is in the index.js file deployed on AWS lambda. I have isolated the problem to the async function. I have tested the function locally and it returns to console.log a list of recipe names. I want to have Alexa say these names. Or at least one name.

If I put the speechOutput assignment inside (as it is now), then I get an error that the 'Speechlet Response is set to null'.

If I tell it to 'return names' and set the external assignment to names or names[0] I get object promise or undefined (respectively).

Everything else in my program works fine and test these two bits apart they work, but putting them together doesn't work. I think that this is a syntax or placement error, but I don't understand the structure or formatting well enough yet (still learning) to understand what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Promise.then` like this:

```
async function main (queryWord) {
  const resp = await Yummly.query(queryWord)
                    .maxTotalTimeInSeconds(1400)
                    .maxResults(20)
                    .minRating(3)
                    .get();
  const names = resp.matches.map(recipe => recipe.recipeName);

  return String(names[0]);

}

main(mainIngredientQuery)
  .catch( error => console.error(error) )
  .then( data => {

    this.response.speak( data );
    this.emit(":responseReady");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this in case anyone else has the same problem.

If you notice, in my original code, I had an async function inside the intent. That didnt work because the intent itself was/is a function. By making the intent function an async function instead, I was able to solve the problem.

The following is working code for an async/await Alexa Intent.

The full index.js is available on my [github](https://github.com/rosabonita/kitchenhelper/blob/master/src/index.js) if you want to take a look, but that will be a more advanced final version. The code below immediately follows up on the original question.

```
"RecommendationIntent": async function main () {
    // delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slots

    let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);

    if (!filledSlots) {
        return;
    }

    console.log("filled slots: " + JSON.stringify(filledSlots));
    // at this point, we know that all required slots are filled.
    let slotValues = getSlotValues(filledSlots);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(slotValues));

    const mainIngredientQuery = slotValues.mainIngredient.resolved;
            const resp = await Yummly.query('chicken')
            .maxTotalTimeInSeconds(1400)
            .maxResults(20)
            .minRating(3)
            .get();
        const names = resp.matches.map(recipe => recipe.recipeName);
        console.log(names);
            const speechOutput = names[0];
            this.response.speak(speechOutput);
            this.emit(":responseReady");
},
```